# How to use Cloudflare SSL with Fortrabbit without SSL enabled on the FR account?

Tags: ssl, https, cloudflare, fortrabbit

I'd like to use Cloudflare "Flexible SSL" with Fortrabbit that has no SSL enabled, i.e. SSL from user to Cloudflare and non-SSL between Cloudflare and Fortrabbit (so that no dedicated LB is required to handle SSL and no additional cost incurred).

When enabling SSL on CF, however, acessing my site, I'm always served the - invalid - Fortrabbit SSL certificate, not the Cloudflare certificate.

Is there a workaround or do do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually sounds like the CloudFlare certificate actually hasn't been issued and/or our proxy isn't running over the record. Kind of hard to look at without knowing the domain...

Comment: The domain in question is www.workinfintech.com. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you have our proxy turned off on the record in your DNS settings (doing a dig doesn't return our IPs). Please login & go to the DNS settings for the domain & check to see if the record is orange clouded.

How to get to DNS settings: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168776-How-do-I-access-my-CloudFlare-DNS-Settings-